# How to remove specific style tag in html using C#

Tags: c#, html, css

Here is my html code:

```
<p><span style="background:lime;Color:Red;">Contrary to popular belief, <b><u>Lorem Ipsum is not simply</u></b> random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from <span style="background:blue;">45 BC, making it over 2000 years</span> old. Richard McClintock, </span><b>
```

From above code, i need to remove the background attributes & value using C# from all the spans. The other values in style tag should remain. Eg:

```
<span style="background:lime;Color:Red;">Contrary to popular belief,.....</span>
```

should look

```
<span style="Color:Red;">Contrary to popular belief,.....</span>
```

Pls help...!

Comment: Check out the HTML Agility Pack from Nuget.

Comment: You could do this easily in jQuery, why does it need to be C#?

Comment: How do you access this HTML?

Comment: I get this html using richtext control. see this thread..http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/79418/400897.aspx#400897

Answer (score 3):

Using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
string html = @"<span style=""background:lime;Color:Red;"">Contrary to popular belief,.....</span>";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

foreach (var span in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("span"))
{
    var style = span.Attributes["style"].Value;
    span.Attributes["style"].Value = String.Join(";", style.Split(';').Where(s => !s.ToLower().Trim().StartsWith("background:")));

}

var newHtml = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$('span').css("background", "")
```

Comment: From question: `...using c#`